# Python TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7

I've looked up other threads on this error "TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable", but I'm not quite understanding what is wrong

```
a = ["Hey","Oh",32,12,"No",41]
b = [23,65,2,7,21,29]
c = ["My","Friends","At","Coding","Dojo"]

def listType(arg):
    new_string = ""
    numSum = 0

for value in type(a):
    if isinstance(value,int) or isinstance(value,float):
        numSum += value
    elif isinstance(value,str):
        new_string += value  
    if new_string and numSum:
        print "String:", new_string
        print "Sum:", numSum
        print "This list is of mixed type"
    elif new_string:
        print "String:", new_string
        print "This list is of string type"
    else:
        print "Sum:", numSum
        print "This list is of integer type" 

print listType(a)
```

Comment: `for value in type(a):` what are you tring to do here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem-Write a program that takes a list and prints a message for each element in
the list, based on that element's data type.

Your program input will always be a list. For each item in the list,
test its data type. If the item is a string, concatenate it onto a new string.
If it is a number, add it to a running sum. At the end of your program print the
string, the number and an analysis of what the list contains. If it contains
only one type, print that type, otherwise, print 'mixed'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you query `type(a)`, you get `list`. You probably want to do a **mapping** of the elements to the corresponding types, so use `map`:

```
def listType(a):
    new_string = ""
    numSum = 0
    for value in map(type,a):
        if isinstance(value,int) or isinstance(value,float):
            numSum += value
        elif isinstance(value,str):
            new_string += value  

    if new_string and numSum:
        print "String:", new_string
        print "Sum:", numSum
        print "This list is of mixed type"
    elif new_string:
        print "String:", new_string
        print "This list is of string type"
    else:
        print "Sum:", numSum
        print "This list is of integer type"

listType(a)
```

Furthermore you should *not* `print` the result of `listType`, since it does not `return` anything, and fix the indentation of the program. I hope it is correct now.